# Wrap promise in function that only returns when promise has been completed

Tags: angular, promise, angular-promise

I want to create some code that executes sequentially as follows:

```
console.log('Called before the function containing a promise');
var result = getSomeData();
console.log('Called after getSomeData() has completed fully');

getSomeData() {
  var stuff = <do something here>;
  return dbGetDocument(stuff).then((result)=>{
      return result;
    });
}

dbGetDocument() is an existing library function (written by someone else) that returns a promise.
```

When running this code the final `console.log` gets executed before the `dbGetDocument.then` has returned it's result.

Comment: Just put the console.log inside the dbGetDocument.then function. Right before returning result

Comment: Sorry, the point of the question was to have something execute after the getSomeData () had completed, not after the dbGetDocument. Console.log was just an example.

Comment: Thanks for the link @estus I still can't work out how to do exactly what I want.

Comment: In Javascript, you can't make a function "wait" to return until an async operation is done.  You just can't.  You will have to restructure your code to pass a callback into the function or have your function return the promise.  Your options are further explained in the question yours is marked a dup of.

Comment: There are answers in dupe question that closely resemble your case with promises. `getSomeData()` should be chained with `.then(...)`.